# How to get value from scene which i have pass from other scene in cocos2d for android?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have PlayScene.cpp
in this scene i have pass value like this:
               CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(
           CCTransitionPageTurn::create(1.0f, ZeroScene::scene(3), true));

Now value is three (ZeroScene::scene(3)) and am able to get this value in ZeroScene

CCScene* ZeroScene::scene(int pups) {
    CCLog("selected pup is :  %i",pups);

```
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

// 'layer' is an autorelease object
ZeroScene *layer = ZeroScene::create();

// add layer as a child to scene
scene->addChild(layer);

// return the scene
return scene;
```

}

Now i want to use this int pups value in ZeroScene.cpp class.
Please help me someone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your own create function which will take this argument. Here is an example :

In your *.h file add :

```
static ZeroScene* create(int pups);
```

And in your *.cpp :

```
ZeroScene* ZeroScene::create(int pups) {

    ZeroScene *zs = new ZeroScene();

    if (zs->init()) {
        zs->autorelease();
        //here write your code to initialize everything
    } else
        zs = NULL;

    return zs;

}
```

Then you simply change the create line in `scene()` method. Everything that I wrote here is basic cocos2d-x initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot Losiowaty . I got other solution for this.